# how do i take set of numbers/ array as input from user

Tags: python-3.x

in this program to find smallest number i get output a blank

```
a = None
z = input("enter 5 numbers")

for x in z:
    if a is None:
        a = x
    elif x<a:
        a=x

print("smallest number is" , a)
```

Comment: This should work if you give numbers without any space. What's your input?

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string, and if the numbers are separated by a space, you need to split the string by space and convert each to an `int` to handle numbers with more than one digit (because iterating over a string will return each digit individually), and you can use Python's built-in `min` function to get the smallest number:

```
z = map(int, input("enter 5 numbers").split())
a = min(z)

# you can really enter any number of numbers this way, not just 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two steps,  split the string, and convert to float.

Here is a corrected version of your program:

```
a = None
z = input("enter 5 numbers: ")

for x in z.split():
    x=float( str(x) )
    if a is None:
        a = x
    elif x<a:
        a=x

print("smallest number is" , a)
```